# Inverse of a function of 2 variables having the complex form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

I would like to  find the inverse of function of 2 variables in then analytic form. Unfortunately, the functions $f,g$ have a "complex" form. Suppose that

\begin{align*}
x=F(u,v) & ,\quad y=G(u,v)\\
u=f(x,y), & \quad v=g(u,v),
\end{align*}

where $f\equiv F^{-1}$ and $g\equiv G^{-1}$. Differentiating the equations leads to

\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
dx\\
dy
\end{array}\right] & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x_{u} & x_{v}\\
y_{u} & y_{v}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
du\\
dv
\end{array}\right],\\
\left[\begin{array}{c}
du\\
dv
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
u_{x} & u_{y}\\
v_{x} & v_{y}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
dx\\
dy
\end{array}\right]\Rightarrow & \left[\begin{array}{c}
dx\\
dy
\end{array}\right]=\frac{1}{\delta^{\prime}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
v_{y} & -u_{y}\\
-v_{x} & u_{x}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
du\\
dv
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}

where $\delta^{\prime}=u_{x}v_{y}-v_{x}u_{y}$, and $\delta=x_{u}y_{v}-x_{v}y_{u}=1/\delta^{\prime}$. Then, differential equations for the inverse are

\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x_{u} & x_{v}\\
y_{u} & y_{v}
\end{array}\right] & =\delta\left[\begin{array}{cc}
v_{y} & -u_{y}\\
-v_{x} & u_{x}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

Let us start with the relatively simple function,

\begin{align*}
x=\cos v\tan u, & y=\frac{\sin v}{\cos u},\\
\end{align*}
then, $h=(\cos^{2}v+\sin^{2}v\sin^{2}u)/\cos^{3}u$, and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos v}{\cos^{2}u}=h\frac{dv}{dy},\quad & \sin v\tan u=h\frac{du}{dy},\\
-\frac{\sin u\sin v}{\cos^{2}u}=h\frac{dv}{dx},\quad & \frac{\cos v}{\cos u}=h\frac{du}{dx}.
\end{align*}

For example, the last equation leads to

\begin{align*}
dx & =\frac{\cos^{2}v+\sin^{2}v\sin^{2}u}{\cos^{2}u\cos v}du\Rightarrow x=\int\frac{\cos^{2}v+\sin^{2}v\sin^{2}u}{\cos^{2}u\cos v}du.
\end{align*}

Do you find these equations helpful for practical finding the inverse
or not? In my opinion, they are not. The "classic" approach leads
to the simple substitution

\begin{align*}
x^{2} & =(1-\sin^{2}v)\tan^{2}u\Rightarrow x^{2}=(\tan^{2}u-y^{2}\sin^{2}u).
\end{align*}

Let us move to the more complex function representing the "engineering
product" that I am not able to solve using any substitution. Since its Jacobian matrix at $u=0, v=0$ is not singular, its inversion at this points exists. However, how to find it...

\begin{align*}
b & =\frac{\pi}{2v}-\frac{2v}{\pi},\quad c=\frac{2}{\pi}u,\quad d=\frac{1-c^{2}}{\sin u-c},\\
x= & \dfrac{\frac{b}{d}\sin u-0.5b}{1+\frac{b^{2}}{d^{2}}}v,\quad y=\dfrac{\frac{d^{2}}{b^{2}}\sin u+0.5d}{1+\frac{d^{2}}{b^{2}}}\cos v.
\end{align*}

**Questions:**

1. Is there any more advanced method for finding the inverse in the analytic
   form or not, or, only numerical methods like Gauss-Newton are available?
2. Is it useful to find some polynomial approximation of the function and find the inverse from the polynomial approximation?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Have you read up on the inverse function theorem?

Comment: @ Triatticus: Sorry, I am engineer, not the mathematician... I have read it, but some consequences may not be clear to me :-)